# postfix disable smtpd error notifications

Tags: postfix

How can i disable postfix smtpd error notifications? Here is message headers:

```
From - Wed Oct 24 20:16:05 2012                                                                                
Return-Path: <double-bounce@example.com>
Received: from mnl-latvia.lv ([unix socket])
     by localhost (Cyrus v2.x.xxx-Debian-2.x.xx-xxxx) with LMTPA;
     Wed, 24 Oct 2012 18:45:44 +0300
X-Sieve: CMU Sieve 2.xxx
Received: by example.com (ESMTP daemon)
    id D9F5315F5A8; Wed, 24 Oct 2012 18:45:44 +0300 (EEST)
Date: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 18:45:44 +0300 (EEST)
From: MAILER-DAEMON@example.com (Mail Delivery System)
To: postmaster@example.com (Postmaster)
Subject: ESMTP daemon SMTP server: errors from 130-12.104-92.cust.bluewin.ch[92.104.12.130]
Message-Id: <20121024154544.D9F5315F5A8@example.com>

Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 mnl-latvia.lv ESMTP daemon ready
 In:  EHLO
 Out: 501 Syntax: EHLO hostname
 In:  HELO
 Out: 501 Syntax: HELO hostname
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like i found answer [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes):
i removed `protocol` from `notify_classes` directive

**protocol**

```
Send the postmaster a transcript of the SMTP session in case of client or server protocol errors. The notification is sent to the address specified with the error_notice_recipient configuration parameter (default: postmaster).
```

Comment: If you provided an answer to your question, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: i need to wait 2 days :)